# PHPExcel OpenOffice Calc (ods) files issue

Tags: php, phpexcel, openoffice-calc

sorry for my english...

I am trying implement phpexcel to read diferent type of files specifically .xls, .xlsx and .ods files.

I am using [this example](https://phpexcel.svn.codeplex.com/svn/trunk/Documentation/Examples/Reader/exampleReader01.php) for my tests

With .xls files... all ok.
with .xlsx files... all ok. but..
with .ods files, it's showing only 1 empty row.

I have used also [this other example](https://phpexcel.svn.codeplex.com/svn/trunk/Documentation/Examples/Reader/exampleReader02.php). At this one I have selected manually the class to use and file to use, but the same problem.

Some idea about this issue?

Regards

Comment: I assume you're using the OOCalc Reader... but answering this is easier if you raise it on the PHPExcel discussion forum - http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions - especially if you can upload your example ods file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it!

phpexcel was not taking the correct actual sheet, I fixed it, setting manually the sheet wanted, adding $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet() before this line.

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
```